# Explain what this assembly language program does in plain English

Tags: assembly, riscv, machine-code

```
    .data
array:  .word   1 2 3 4 5
mfact:  .word   100
dfact:  .word   20

    .text
main:   lui s0, 0x10010     # U format  4 cycles
    lw  t0, 20(s0)      # I format  5 cycles
    lw  t1, 24(s0)      # I format  5 cycles
    or  s1, zero, zero  # R format  4 cycles
    ori s2, zero, 5     # I format  4 cycles

loop:   slli    s3, s1, 2       # I format  4 cycles
    add s4, s3, s0      # R format  4 cycles
    lw  t2, 0(s4)       # I format  5 cycles
    mul t3, t2, t0      # R format  10 cycles
    div t4, t3, t1      # R format  40 cycles
    sw  t4, 0(s4)       # S format  4 cycles
    addi    s1, s1, 1       # I format  4 cycles
    blt s1, s2, loop    # B format  3 cycles

exit:   ori a7, zero, 10    # I format  4 cycles
    ecall           # I format  3 cycles
```

The question does not have any more information. I think the program divides and multiplies the numbers 1-5 until it reaches 0 then it stops. Am I correct about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program is supposed to take each element of an array of 5 word and multiply it with the first word after the array, then divide the result with the second element after the array. However there is some problems:
1- you need to add com between the words of the array.
2- you need to declare main as a global function, so that the linker can find it. Otherwise you will have an undefined reference error.
3- the `lui s0, 0x10010` could be problematic. Are you sure the linker will put array at this address? Did you modified the linker script to force it? IF you are not sure of what the linker will do . It will be better to declare array as an object and use it directly with and lui + addi.

The code will be:

```
    .data
    .type   array, @object
    .size   array, 20
array:  .word   1, 2, 3, 4, 5
mfact:  .word   100
dfact:  .word   20

    .text
    .global main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    lui s0, %hi(array)      # U format  4 cycles
    addi s0, s0, %lo(array) # I format  4 cycles
    lw  t0, 20(s0)          # I format  5 cycles
    lw  t1, 24(s0)          # I format  5 cycles
    or  s1, zero, zero      # R format  4 cycles
    ori s2, zero, 5         # I format  4 cycles

loop:
    slli    s3, s1, 2       # I format  4 cycles
    add s4, s3, s0          # R format  4 cycles
    lw  t2, 0(s4)           # I format  5 cycles
    mul t3, t2, t0          # R format  10 cycles
    div t4, t3, t1          # R format  40 cycles
    sw  t4, 0(s4)           # S format  4 cycles
    addi    s1, s1, 1       # I format  4 cycles
    blt s1, s2, loop        # B format  3 cycles

exit:
    ori a7, zero, 10        # I format  4 cycles
    ecall                   # I format  3 cycles
    .size   main, .-main
```

Comment: I suspect the OP might have been running their code in a simulator like RARS, which (like MARS for MIPS) has simple defaults about where to put the .data section.  And might not need `main` to be `.global`.  Those are good corrections, but that might explain why the code worked at all in some environment.

Comment: Note that you can generally skip the `addi s0, s0, %lo(array)`, and use it in later loads like `lw t0, %lo(array)+20(s0)`, as long as you know the array wasn't close to the end of a 4k boundary that would make `%lo(array)+20` no longer fit in a 12-bit sign-extended immediate.